# Maven Error: Could not find or load main class MLSH-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I used Maven to make dependency and build jar file for my project. I generated the Jar file successfully, but I encountered the following problem:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class MLSH-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.Jar
```

I used the following plugins in my POM file:

### POM.XML

```
<plugin> 
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId> 
  <configuration> 
    <archive> 
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>metric_Learning.Variable_Initialization</mainClass> 
      </manifest>
    </archive>  
    <descriptorRefs>  
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>  
  </configuration>  
</plugin>
```

What you recommend me to solve the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the configuration of the plugin, you need to specify the main class to be added to the manifest, as described [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) to make the generated JAR file executable.

```
<configuration>
    <!-- ... -->
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.whatever.Main</mainClass>
        </manifest>
    </archive>
    <!-- ... -->
</configuration>
```

Also, (unless you changed the default naming of the JAR file containing the dependencies), you need to execute the one that ends with `...-with-dependencies.jar`

Comment: <configuration> <archive> <manifest>             <mainClass>com.MLSH.metric_Learning.Variable_Initialization.Main</mainClass>      </manifest>  </archive>          </configuration>

Answer (score 0):

```
Add the following in your POM file:

<archive>
    <manifest>
      <mainClass>enter the full package to the main class</mainClass>
    </manifest>
 </archive>
```